# Repeating pattern X amount of times in LIKE

Tags: sql-server, pattern-matching, like, regex

I took a look at the documentation for patterns from Microsoft (can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx)), and from what I understood, it doesn't say a way for a pattern to repeat a limited number of times. It's either the wildcard (which goes on indefinitely) or looking for a specific character in a location, with each location typed out independently. Is there a way to type out "Pattern X repeated Y times"?

For example, if I wanted to look up account numbers that have exactly 5 digits, what I have now is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE account LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Is there a shorthand way to do that?

Answer (score 11):

Yes. Function [`REPLICATE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms174383.aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE account LIKE REPLICATE('[0-9]', 5) ;
```